# Merge tags php-ffmpeg and ffmpeg-php

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

In theory these two tags are supposed to represent several different PHP libraries/extensions/`ffmpeg` wrappers:

- [ffmpeg-php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ffmpeg-php) is intended for FFmpegPHP and ffmpeg-php (a dead project since 2007).
- [php-ffmpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php-ffmpeg) is intended for PHP-FFMpeg.

Users tend not to discriminate a difference and often apply both or either arbitrarily regardless of the project being used. Users also blindly apply them to `ffmpeg` cli tool usage questions within PHP scripts.

We don't need two nearly identical tags that functionally have no difference. It doesn't matter which one becomes the main tag, but [ffmpeg-php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ffmpeg-php) does have more questions.

Comment: I can make quick work of a merge and synonymization, if I can get some semblance of consensus from the ffmpeg experts that this is a good idea. It looks like you know what you're doing in this arena, so one more expert would convince me. I would definitely prefer that people *not* go out and manually retag the 28 questions, unless we decide that the distinction between the libraries really needs to be preserved in the tag system.

Comment: In the mean time it would be nice if someone with 20K Rep could edit the excerpts of both [tag:php-ffmpeg] and [tag:ffmpeg-php] to mention that those tags are only for some specific libraries, and that if the question is just about ffmeg and php, then instead it should be tagged [tag:ffmpeg] + [tag:php].

Comment: Are you telling me the `-` operator is commutative?

Comment: No, I'm worried about seeing questions being tagged PHP + FFMPEG + PHP-FFMPEG and seeing another Meta topic asking to do something about it. So it could be an opportunity to restrict the usage of [tag:php-ffmpeg] and [tag:ffmpeg-php].

Comment: The main problem here is that the developers of the latter library should have atleast checked if there were any similarly named libraries. Option 1 is bad (as we would lose the classification of the posts into the specific questions), Option 2 is _worse_ (as we would constantly get a load of wrongly tagged questions). I am open for any other thoughts/ideas.  Have you come across a different plan in the past 2 years?

Comment: @BhargavRao We are overthinking it. There is no real classification. Usage is generally arbitrary. [tag:php-ffmpeg] just needs to be a synonym of [tag:ffmpeg-php]. We can simply allow the users to continue their behavior (because they will regardless) and things will be somewhat more organized and less fragmented. php-ffmpeg only has 63 questions anyway, so its not going to be a big change.

Comment: Ah, sounds cool then. We just would need to update the tag wiki of single tag to reflect that it needs to be used for both libraries (though, we're pretty sure that no one will use the deprecated library). Synonymized.

Comment: @BhargavRao Thanks. I updated the tag wiki.